# How do I add a Remove button that removes the entire row with localstorage for shoppingcart

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopping-cart

Im new to javascript, I wanted to add a remove button on my shopping cart, how do I make one that removes 1 row from the local storage. My table for my shopping cart is in my javascript and I cant figure out how to add another function for the Remove butoon

```
function displayCart(){
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    let productContainer = document.querySelector(".products");
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
    
    console.log(cartItems);
    if( cartItems && productContainer){
        productContainer.innerHTML = '';
        Object.values(cartItems).map(item => {
            productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="product">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeItems()" >Remove</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <img src="./img/${item.tag}.jpg">
                <span>${item.name}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                ₱${item.price}.00
                </div>
                <div class="quantity">&nbsp;<span>${item.inCart}</span>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="total">
                    ₱${item.inCart * item.price}.00
                </div>
            `
        });

        productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="basketTotalContainer">
            <h4 class="basketTotalTitle">
                Cart Total
                </h4>
                <h4 class="basketTotal">
                ₱${cartCost}.00
                </h4>
        `;
    }
}
```

I tried putting another function, localstorage.removeItem(); above that function but it doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### remove item from object array

An example of an approach that could be used to manage your shopping cart is described here.

The cart is stored in an *array of objects* which is ideally suited to storing in local storage (and network transfer) as a json string, and makes for easy rendering of the data to the html page. The example data structure I have used for the example is:

```
    const cart = [
    {name: "shoes", price: 85, tag:"img_001", inCart: 1}, 
    {name: "hat", price: 42, tag:"img_002", inCart: 1},
    {name: "belt", price: 24, tag:"img_003", inCart: 2}
    ] // end cart array
```

To store the data in localstorage, the array would be converted to a string using `JSON.stringify(cart)`, and the retrieved string would be converted to a javascript array using `JSON.parse(stringName)` (where stringName is whatever variable the read local storage was stored in).

**the remove function has to know which item had its remove button clicked**

the easiest way to achieve this is to include the index of each object in the `cart` array to it's relevant button when the cart is rendered to the html document.

So, a `renderCart()` function (to read the cart data and render it in the html document) would include a modified version of the button markup:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeItems(${index})" >Remove</button>
```

Notice the `onclick` attribute now includes an `index` argument for your `removeItems()` function. The value of `index` has come from an optional argument in the `array.map` method (which can supply both the element, in this case an object, and its index position in the array):

```
array.map((element,index)=> {// both the element and its numerical index are available here;}
```

The `removeItems` function now receives the index of the `cart` array holding the data relevant to the button that was clicked. The index can be used to remove that element from the array, before calling the `renderCart()` function to display the modified car in the html document.:

```
 function removeItems(elementIndex) {
console.log(elementIndex);
cart.splice(elementIndex, 1);
renderCart();
// code to replace local storage copy of cart goes here;
 } // end function removeItems
```

The function should also then replace the localStorage version of the data, for which you will need another function that converts it to a json string and sets the data to localstorage.

**demonstration snippet**

The following snippet demonstrates these principles and should be adaptable to your particular case:

```js
const cart = [
{name: "shoes", price: 85, tag:"img_001", inCart: 1}, 
{name: "hat", price: 42, tag:"img_002", inCart: 1},
{name: "belt", price: 24, tag:"img_003", inCart: 2}
] // end cart array

productContainer = document.getElementById('container');

renderCart();

function renderCart() {
productContainer.innerHTML = "";
cart.map((item, index) => {
            productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="product">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeItems(${index})" >Remove</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <img src="./img/${item.tag}.jpg">
                <span>${item.name}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                price (each): $${item.price}.00
                </div>
                <div class="quantity">&nbsp;quantity: <span>${item.inCart}</span>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="total">
                total: $${item.inCart * item.price}.00
                </div>           `
        });
 } // end function renderCart
 
 function removeItems(elementIndex) {
console.log(elementIndex);
cart.splice(elementIndex, 1);
renderCart();
// code to replace local storage copy of cart goes here;
 } // end function removeItems
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```